# Cannot play sound from assets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I have an issue with audioplayer dependency. I'm trying to implement sounds effect from my assets in my app but something went wrong and I don't know what. I've initialized AudioCache with prefix as location of files but in my method when I am awaiting for soung i have no option as 'play'. What am I doing wrong?

```
class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  // initialize audio cache
  AudioCache player = AudioCache(prefix: '/assets/sounds/');
  
  // pick random word from wordToGuess list
  String word = wordToGuess[Random().nextInt(wordToGuess.length)];
  List guessedLetters = ['f', 'l'];
  int points = 0;
  int status = 0;
 

  playSound(String sound) async {
    await player. // here is no method as 'play'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this

```
flutter:
  assets:
   - assets/
```

in you pubspec.yaml

do.  `flutter pub get`

You can also try this package and follow the step here
[AssetsAudioPlayer](https://flutterawesome.com/play-music-audio-stored-in-assets-files-directly-from-flutter/)